# Using PHP to validate form before submitting to custom action URL

Tags: php, forms, validation

I will preface this by saying that I currently have a very limited knowledge about PHP, so I apologize if this seems elementary.

I have an existing HTML form that's fully styled with jQuery validation.  The form data is being submitted to a third party email campaign manager.  I would like to include some additional server side validation.  Is there a way to run a PHP function that if the errors array = 0 to then submit the form to a custom URL action?

Every tutorial I find assumes you're pushing the form data to a custom built server, so they always leave the form action blank.  I only want to use PHP for additional validation and that's it.

Any guidance would greatly help.  Here's my form code.

```
<form action="http://customURL-for-campaign-manager" onsubmit="return validate()"  method="post">
    First name:<input type="text" name="customFname" id="name"/>
    Last Name:</div><input type="text" name="customLname" id="LastName" />
    Email Address:<input type="text" name="customEname" />
    Zipcode (optional):<input type="text" name="customZname" />
<input type="submit" value="Sign Up" />
</form>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

you could just ajax call your own server in validate() and have it check the form inputs. if you like the values, you can have the client submit the form to the third party server.

Answer (score 0):

You could use cURL here (http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php)

It means, that your html-file sends data to your validator.php, that validates and possible sanitizes your code. After that, you either give error or repost data using cURL to the final destination.